# Access IUrlHelper inside DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Following a migration to ASP.Net core, the following handler does not work. I cannot see how to get access to `IUrlHelper` from the `HttpRequestMessage` as was previously possible, and can't find a package with relevant extension methods.

The handler is added using `config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LinkDecoratorHandler());`

Can anyone help?

```
 public class LinkDecoratorHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {

     protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage 
        request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;

                if (!(response.Content is ObjectContent))
                {
                    return response;
                }

                var entity = (response.Content as ObjectContent).Value as ILinkedEntity;

                var enumeration = (response.Content as ObjectContent).Value as IEnumerable<ILinkedEntity>;

                if (entity != null || enumeration != null)
                {
                    //no longer available
                    var helper = request.GetUrlHelper();

                //blah
                }

                return response;
            });
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you have the above code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `LinkDecoratorHandler` is instantiated via dependency injection then you could inject an instance of [`IActionContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to get the current `ActionContext`. From there, you can [create your own UrlHelper instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Routing_UrlHelper__ctor_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_).